# Spring Boot MongoDB to get the sum of a field in a document returned by API

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, api, rest

I am new to Spring Boot MongoDB. I am developing a small application for monthly expenses.

I want to calculate the total sum of the expense amount returned for the documents in a particular date range.

I'm able to fetch the documents within a given date range.

How do I capture the amount field alone and total it for the fetched date range?

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/findBetDates/{stexpdate}/{edexpdate}")
List<mydataExp> getByExpdateBetw(@PathVariable String stexpdate, @PathVariable String edexpdate) {
    return expenseRepository.findExpDateBetw(stexpdate, edexpdate); 
}
```

Repository:

```
@Query("{'expdate' : { $gte: ?0, $lte: ?1 } }")   
List<mydataExp> findExpDateBetw(String stexpdate, String edexpdate);
```

Model:

```
@Document(collection = "mydataExp")
public class mydataExp {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String expdate;
    private String exptype;
    private int expamt;
}
```

Postman Response for the API:

**http://localhost:8080/findBetDates/12-01-2020/12-02-2020**

```
[
    {
        "id": 121982,
        "expdate": "12-01-2020",
        "exptype": "Rent",
        "expamt": 1000
    },
    {
        "id": 121984,
        "expdate": "12-02-2020",
        "exptype": "Indian Stores",
        "expamt": 54
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you need to use projection and get only the `expamt` for all object.You can use [projection](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-projections-aggregations#2-projections-using-mongorepository) as mention in the link. We put 1 for all the field we want to retrieve.
In your case the query would be

```
@Query(value="{'expdate' : { $gte: ?0, $lte: ?1 } }", fields="{expamt : 1}")
```

P.S. Here's the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html) subheading 6.3.2